# inserting datetimes into database using java

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, prepared-statement

I am wanting to insert a datetime into a MySql data base using Java and a prepared statement:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
PreparedStatement stmnt = db.PreparedStatement("INSERT INTO Run " +
                       "(Time) VALUE (?) ");
    stmnt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime()));
    stmnt.executeQuery();
```

NOTE: there is currently an error - cannot find symbol (java.sql.Date) line 4 here

db is an instance of a sort of wrapper class that exposes what I need from java.sql - its just getting a prepared statement from my connection object here.

Time (the column) is a date time in my database, and I can only see setDate and setTime method but I want to store both - also my code does not work anyway ;-)

If anyone could give me some pointers on inserting a combined date time (current time would be a great help as that's my first goal) into a MySql DB using a prepared statement I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor for java.sql.Date takes a long (milliseconds since 1970) [java.sql.Date](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long))
To get milliseconds from a java.uitl.Calendar, you use [`cal.getTimeInMillis()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis())

Your code would be:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
PreparedStatement stmnt = db.PreparedStatement("INSERT INTO Run " + "(Time) VALUE (?) ");
stmnt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
stmnt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Excellent! thats the problem, stange how the error seemed so unrelated.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

the following code should allow you to insert a date with millisecond accuracy. I have used it with HSQLDB, Sybase, SQL-Server and MySql without any problems.

```
java.util.Date date = getMyDate();
if (date == null) {
    statement.setNull(insertionIndex, Types.TIMESTAMP);
} else {
    statement.setTimestamp(insertionIndex, new Timestamp (date.getTime()));
}
```